# Android SDK packages I need not showing up?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, google-api

Im running into the issue of my project requiring Google APIs 19. When I try to download them in the SDK Manager, they don't show up. I have the correct links enabled and such.

Here is what mine looks like:

[image: Here is what mine looks like:]

And then here is what I need mine to look like:

[image: And then here is what I need mine to look like:]